# Product import raising an error but the script is stopping, not being handled by catch{}

Tags: product, error, exception

I am importing some products. Generally this works fine and when it does raise an error, I skip that item because I handle it using try / catch. I have an issue sometimes though where the catch isn't triggered despite an error being raised.

For instance, one product threw an error here in `Catalog\Product\Type\Configurable.php` with this line:

```
foreach ($this->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
            $this->getProduct($product)->setData($attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode(), null);
        }
```

basically it was reporting that `$attribute` was null (and it threw the error when debugging using xdebug) however, instead of then going into my `catch` code, it just stopped the script. I have already fixed the issue that caused this BUT I need to know how to catch things like this and skip / log the item, not just stop the script.

Can anyone lend some advice please?

Comment: Hmm, turns out it's raising a PHP Fatal error which is the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatal Error's will cause the Magento error handling and any other Error handling to fail. This is by design in PHP. With that in mind, I am now logging the errors using a shutdown event.

```
register_shutdown_function(array($this, "fatalErrorHandler"));
function fatalErrorHandler() {
    $error = error_get_last();

    if($error !== null) {
        //Do some primitive logging
    }
    return;
}
```